# have different configuration variable value on publish to production

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2022, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

In `Program.cs` I read a configuration var like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var host = builder.Configuration["host"]
```

In my development I need this var to be
`http://localhost/myapp`

but when I publish (using VS2022 `publish`) to production I need it to be
`https://www.example.com`

I tried creating multiple `appsettings.json`, .. `appsettings.envName.json` files, but when I publish they all get copied as is to the publish folder, regardless of what
`<EnvironmentName>envName</EnvironmentName>` I have in the publish `.pubxml` file.

Comment: Where is the code about URLs? You can use the UseUrls extension method on the WebApplicationBuilder object in Program.cs. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#urls. For setting up URLs in a development or production environment, you can refer to this tutorial: https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/.